# i want to resize my image but some image save blank

Tags: php

```
function image_resize($src, $dst, $width, $height, $crop=0){
    if(!list($w, $h) = getimagesize($src)) return "Unsupported picture type!";
    $type = strtolower(substr(strrchr($src,"."),1));
    if($type == 'jpeg') $type = 'jpg';
    switch($type){
        case 'jpg': $img = imagecreatefromjpeg($src); break;
        case 'png': $img = imagecreatefrompng($src); break;
        default : return "Unsupported picture type!";
    }
    if($crop){
        if($w < $width or $h < $height) return "Picture is too small!";
        $ratio = max($width/$w, $height/$h);
        $h = $height / $ratio;
        $x = ($w - $width / $ratio) / 2;
        $w = $width / $ratio;
    }
    else{
        if($w < $width and $h < $height) return "Picture is too small!";
        $ratio = min($width/$w, $height/$h);
        $width = $w * $ratio;
        $height = $h * $ratio;
        $x = 0;
    }
    $new = imagecreatetruecolor($width, $height);
    if($type == "gif" or $type == "png"){
        imagecolortransparent($new, imagecolorallocatealpha($new, 0, 0, 0, 127));
        imagealphablending($new, false);
        imagesavealpha($new, true);
    }
    imagecopyresampled($new, $img, 0, 0, $x, 0, $width, $height, $w, $h);
    switch($type){
        case 'jpg': imagejpeg($new, $dst); break;
        case 'png': imagepng($new, $dst); break;
    }
    return true;
}
```

and i call it like

```
image_resize($path . $NewNameImage, $path . "thumbs/".$NewNameImage, 50, 50, 1);
```

but i see in server save black image for some images
plz help me

Comment: try to unset variable i hope this will works for you !!!  E.g: unset($imgObject);
    unset($source);
    unset($image_p);
    unset($image);

Comment: @BhAvikGajjar where i do it? can you explain more? or can edit my code? imagecreatefromjpeg or imagecreatefromjpeg is false return